# É possível fazer uma condição dentro de um Select?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou realizando uma consulta usando `Select`, para selecionar apenas os campos necessários e consequentemente ter maior performance.

Na minha `View` o usuário pode escolher determinados campos a serem carregados

Meu `ViewModel`

```
public class CliViewModel {
   public bool CarregarNome {get;set;}
}
```

e no meu `select`

```
var entity = context.Clientes.AsNoTracking()
             .Select(cli => new { 
               if(viewModel.CarregarNome) {
                  x.Nome
               }
             }).ToList();
```

Claro que essa expressão da erro, mas há alguma forma de fazer algo parecido ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, mas não com o condicional dentro do `Select`:

```
var entity = context.Clientes
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToList();

if(viewModel.CarregarNome) 
{
    var retorno = entity.Select(x => new { x.Nome });
} else {
    var retorno = entity.Select(x => new { /* Descreva os atributos aqui */ });
}
```

Se o objetivo é performance, você vai ter que usar [o pacote NuGet de Dynamic LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) mais ou menos assim:

```
String columns = "";
if (viewModel.CarregarNome) {
    columns += "Nome"
}
var entity = context.Clientes.AsNoTracking()
         .Select("new(" + columns + ")").ToList();
```

Comment: Depende do seu retorno poderia ter a condicional assim                        var retorno = entity.Select(x => new { Nome = viewModel.CarregarNome == true ? x.Nome : String.Empty });

Comment: Isso na verdade é um chuncho, e `Nome` é definido assim mesmo, sem qualquer ganho de performance.